# placing <td> side by side in laravel5.2

Tags: laravel

I need help regarding the following issue:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 marquee_text">
           <marquee behavior="" direction="">
              <tr><td> {{ $post->id }} {{ $post->title }}</td> </td></tr>
           </marquee>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Could anyone help me arranging the rows and `<td></td>` in the following order?

```
<tr><td>id-1 title-1</td><td>id-2 title-2</td></tr>
<tr><td>id-3 title-3</td><td>id-4 title-4</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the `@foreach` within the `<marquee>` and use modulo (`$i % 2 == 0`) to target one post out of two for `<tr></tr>` (rows):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 marquee_text">
       <marquee behavior="" direction="">
          @foreach($posts as $i => $post)
          {{ $i % 2 == 0 ? '<tr>': '' }}
          <td>{{ $post->id }} {{ $post->title }}</td>
          {{ $i % 2 != 0 ? '</tr>': '' }}
          @endforeach
       </marquee>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @foreach ($posts->chunk(2) as $chunk)
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12 marquee_text">
             <marquee behavior="" direction="">
               @foreach ($chunk as $post)
               <tr>
                 <td> {{ $post->id }} {{ $post->title }}</td> 
               </tr>
               @endforeach
             </marquee>
           </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

Can you try using Laravel `chunk` helper?